# Mean of last N rows of pandas dataframe if the previous rows meet a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumsum

I have a pandas dataframe like

```
   index    start end  label
   0          2     5    0
   1          3     8    1
   2          4     8    0
   3          5     9    1
   4          6    10    0
   5          7    10    1
   6          8    11    1
   7          9    12    0
```

I want a new column 'mean'; where the value is the mean of the previous rows `label` with the condition `df['start']<df['end']`

Example,

for index 1, `df['mean'] = (df[0]['label']+ df[1]['label'])/2`

for index 3,  `df['mean'] = (df[1]['label']+ df[2]['label']+ df[3]['label'])/3` ; here we ignore index 0 as `df[3]['start']<df[0]['end']` condition does not satisfy.

similarly, for index 7,  `df['mean'] = (df[4]['label']+ df[5]['label']+ df[6]['label']+ df[7]['label'])/4` ; as for index 0,1,2,3; `df[7]['start']<df[i]['end']` condition does not satisfy.

So the final output would be

```
  index    start end  label     mean
       0          2     5    0  0
       1          3     8    1  1/2
       2          4     8    0  1/3
       3          5     9    1  2/3
       4          6    10    0  2/4
       5          7    10    1  3/5
       6          8    11    1  3/4
       7          9    12    0  2/4
```

I was trying using `cumsum`; but I am not sure how to put the condition.

Comment: I like the question so marked it up. Just a slight suggestion - add how to create dataframe to your question and how to create the final result. pd.DataFrame([
    [2,5,0],
    [3,8,1],
    [4,8,0],
    [5,9,1],
    [6,10,0],
    [7,10,1],
    [8,11,1],
    [9,12,0]],columns=['start','end','label']) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be fair I decided to try and compare three types of approaches:

1. using loop
2. using parallel loop (numba)
3. using matrix

Here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
from numba import njit, prange

import numpy as np

from timeit import timeit

from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal

big_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000, 3)), columns=["start", "end", "label"])

def cond_cumsum_matrix(df):
    mask_matrix = (
        (df.start.to_numpy().reshape(1,-1).T < df.end.to_numpy()) 
        & (df.index.to_numpy() <= np.arange(0,len(df)).reshape(1, -1).T)
    )
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):
        df_add = pd.DataFrame(
            (np.matmul(
                (
                    (mask_matrix) 

                ), df.label.to_numpy()
            )
        ) / (mask_matrix.sum(axis=-1)),
            columns = ["mean"]
        )
    return df_add

def cond_cumsum_parallel_loop(df):
    @njit
    def numba_cond_cumsum_parallel_loop(label, start, end):
        cumsum = []        
        
        for i in prange(len(label)):
            running = 0
            count = 0
            for j in prange(i+1):
                if start[i] < end[j] :
                    running += label[j]
                    count += 1
            if count == 0:
                cumsum.append(np.nan)            
            else:
                cumsum.append(running/count)
        return cumsum
        
    return pd.DataFrame(
        numba_cond_cumsum_parallel_loop(
        df.label.to_numpy(),
        df.start.to_numpy(),
        df.end.to_numpy(),
    ), columns=["mean"],) 

def cond_cumsum_loop(df):
    start = df.start.tolist()
    end = df.end.tolist()
    label = df.label.tolist()
    
    cumsum = []                
    for index, row in df.iterrows():

        running = 0
        count = 0
        for j in range(index+1):
            if row.start < end[j] :
                running += label[j]
                count += 1
            
        if count == 0:
            cumsum.append(np.nan)
            
        else:
            cumsum.append(running/count)
        
    return pd.DataFrame(
        cumsum,
    columns=["mean"],)

assert_frame_equal(cond_cumsum_matrix(big_df), cond_cumsum_loop(big_df))
assert_frame_equal(cond_cumsum_matrix(big_df), cond_cumsum_parallel_loop(big_df))

repetitions = 5
print(f"cond_cumsum_loop runs {timeit(lambda: cond_cumsum_loop(big_df), number=repetitions)/repetitions} seconds")
print(f"cond_cumsum_parallel_loop runs {timeit(lambda: cond_cumsum_parallel_loop(big_df), number=repetitions)/repetitions} seconds")
print(f"cond_cumsum_matrix runs {timeit(lambda: cond_cumsum_matrix(big_df), number=repetitions)/repetitions} seconds")
```

and here is what result it gives:

```
cond_cumsum_loop runs 1.2179410583339632 seconds
cond_cumsum_parallel_loop runs 0.07655967501923441 seconds
cond_cumsum_matrix runs 0.004219983238726854 seconds
```

Of course the code could be improved so the comparison is not ideal but anyway the conclusion is that although matrix still wins in performance with using O(n^2) additional memory, a parallel loop gives a somewhat decent performance with using only O(n) additional memory.

Comment: No prob. If the answer suits you could accept it. And/or mark it up

Answer (score 0):

Here is your result.

```
import numpy as np
mask_matrix = (
    (df.start.to_numpy().reshape(1,-1).T < df.end.to_numpy()) 
    & (df.index.to_numpy() <= np.arange(0,len(df)).reshape(1, -1).T)
)
df_add = pd.DataFrame(
    (np.matmul(
        (
            (mask_matrix) 
            
        ), df.label.to_numpy()
    )
) / (mask_matrix.sum(axis=-1)),
    columns = ["mean"]
)
df = pd.concat([df, df_add], axis=1)
```

When we create the matrix we use O(n^2) of additional space. Hopefully it is not a problem. Otherwise need to use a loop which I don't personally like when using vectorized computations.

A few additional comments:
df.start.to_numpy().reshape(1,-1).T < df.end.to_numpy() basically compares where start is below end for each row. This is the result:

```
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False],
   [False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False],
   [False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False]])
```

(df.index.to_numpy() <= np.arange(0,len_).reshape(1, -1).T) restricts previous result to only rows that are precedent to current one. This mask looks like this:

```
array([[ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
   [ True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
   [ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

Final mask_matrix (elementwise multiplication of previous two matrices) looks like this

```
array([[ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False]])
```

Now multiplying this mask_matrix by vector df.label gives almost what we need. Just need to elementwise divide by the sum of True in mask_matrix

Comment: Getting an error: `NameError: name 'len_' is not defined`

Comment: Sorry replaced `len_` with `len(df)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a less performant solution (looping over each row should generally be avoided in Pandas) but one that is hopefully accessible as a starting point that you can then optimize:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [2,5,0],
    [3,8,1],
    [4,8,0],
    [5,9,1],
    [6,10,0],
    [7,10,1],
    [8,11,1],
    [9,12,0]],columns=['start','end','label'])


for index, row in df.iterrows():

    if index == 0:
        df.at[index, 'cumulative_mean'] = 0

    else:
        current_row_start = row['start']
        previous_rows_as_df = df.loc[0:index] # create a DF which is all the previous rows
        
        for p_index, p_row in previous_rows_as_df.iterrows():
            if current_row_start < p_row['end']:
                previous_rows_as_df.at[p_index, 'include'] = True

        df.at[index, 'cumulative_mean'] = previous_rows_as_df[previous_rows_as_df['include'] == True]['label'].mean()
```